# Index match with mround only working on some values

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am trying to use index match with mround, but for some reason it only works for some values. If I have the following table:
[image]

And I want to try to find the rounded 0.64 in the table. The green error message says "A value is not available to the formula or function." I evaluated the formula but it came up with N/A after calculating the match function. What's happening here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$21,MATCH(ROUND(D1,1),$A$1:$A$21,0)).
```

Your `Mround` was messing it all up.

the `Mround` has a known limitation with the multiplier of 0.1.

Comment: This worked. Any idea why MROUND wasn't working? I even tried using VALUE(D5) and that still didn't work